# Updating firestore data based on some specific condition in Angular. SnapshotChanges() Issue

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have to update the data in realtime with some specific conditions. i.e. in my case, I've to update the databases cloudfirestore based on session id and user ID. Below is the code.

```
let docIdOfNonExistance = this.firestore.collection(
      'testdb',
      (ref_non_user) =>
        ref_non_user
          .where('userId', '>', result.userId)
          .where('sessionId', '==', result.sessionId)
    );

    docIdOfNonExistance.snapshotChanges().subscribe((ref_non_user: any) => {
      console.log(ref_non_user);
      ref_non_user.forEach((doc_list) => {
        this.firestore
          .collection('testdb')
          .doc(doc_list.payload.doc.id)
          .update({ status: 'pending' });
      });
    });
```

Everything works perfect, realtime data is correctly updating
But the problem is after updating the data it comes to the previous state automatically. and Multiple times update is occurring. I have tried to unsubscribe() method also, but for the second time due to the unsubscribe method, data is not updating real-time.

Also, we can directly update with docId but here I have to update based on sessionId and userId.

Please help me while using in this way how multiple times triggering occurs automatically.
I found that this is mostly happening due to snapshotChanges() method.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach might be to add a `take(1)` to the chain:

```
docIdOfNonExistance.take(1).snapshotChanges().subscribe((ref_non_user: any) => {
  ...
```

From what I can determine from the documentation, this should also work:

```
docIdOfNonExistance.get().subscribe((ref_non_user: any) => {
  ...
```

If it indeed does work, I'd prefer this syntax, as it's closer to how the underlying JavaScript SDK would do this.

Comment: Hi @Frank van Puffelen, thanks for the answer, but unfortunately none of them is working for me.